# Application uploads image successfully without Jmeter, but fails to upload image when recorded under Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, ruby-jmeter

Step 1:  Login to application and upload an image for Admin profile.
         Application uploads image successfully without been recorded in Jmeter.
Step 2 : Start Jmeter, add a thread group.
Step 3 : Add HTTP(S) test script recorder, go to HTTP sampler settings and
         select type as "Java".
Step 3:  Select target controller as Thread Group, configure Firefox to port
         8080 and start the test script recorder to upload the image.
Result: Application fails to upload image successfully when script is recorded 
        by Jmeter.
Error displayed is :"java.io.FileNotFoundException: My image.jpg (The system cannot find the file specified)"

How to upload image successfully with Jmeter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For successful image upload recording the image needs to be in the JMeter's working directory - usually /bin folder of your JMeter installation so copy your image there and retry.

If it doesn't help - look for the following lines in *jmeter.log* file

```
jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=D:\jmeter\bin
jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =D:\jmeter\bin
```

it will allow you to determine the correct location for the image.

For more information on the subject check out [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for your kind help, the images are uploaded now.